# How to deploy Einstein Discovery Model and Stories with Metadata deployment (ant)

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, einstein-analytics

What I need to do if I want to deploy Einstein Discovery Model , which all components do I need to Pick in my package.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a help doc that covers how to [Package, Promote, and Distribute your Predictions](https://dreamevent.secure.force.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_bi_edd_predict_package.htm&type=5&release=230).

The metadata types are the following:

1. [Discovery Prediction (DiscoveryGoal)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_discoverygoal.htm)
2. [Discovery Model (DiscoveryAIModel)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_discoveryaimodel.htm)

The following package.xml should pull what you need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>DiscoveryAIModel</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>DiscoveryGoal</name>
    </types>
    <version>52.0</version>
</Package>
```